# Select and Set Value in SQL Statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I have a rather quirky question. In a `SELECT` statement can I set a default value?

In the following query I want `boolItem` to always be false (not retrieved from the database). Crazy I know but bear with me as I explain why.

```
SELECT id, boolItem = False
FROM MyTable;
```

I am working with a large existing SQL database and project. I am querying data and returning them as `Action` C# objects. An action can be custom made by the user or a standard one. This is signified by a property `IsCustom`.

```
public class Action
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCustom { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

In the SQL database custom actions are stored in the table `custom_actions` and standard actions are in the table `actions`.

I retrieve and store `Action` objects using the below code. I want to make the query of the `actions` table always set the property `IsCustom` to false. And the query of the `custom_actions` table always set the property `IsCustom` to true. I am using the query `SELECT a.id AS Id, a.is_custom = false AS IsCustom` which is not valid code because the table doesn't have a `is_custom` column but its to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.Action>> ExecuteAsync (IDbConnection conn, IDbTransaction transition, long userId)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT a.id AS Id, a.is_custom = false AS IsCustom
                   FROM actions a
                   INNER JOIN members_actions ma ON  a.id = ma.action_id AND is_custom = false
                   WHERE ma.member_id = :userId
                   UNION
                   SELECT a.id AS Id, a.is_custom = true AS IsCustom 
                   FROM custom_actions a
                   INNER JOIN members_actions ma ON  a.id = ma.action_id AND is_custom = true
                   WHERE ma.member_id = :userId;";

    return await conn.QueryAsync<Models.Action> (sql, new {userId = userId}, transition);
}
```

Table 'Actions' Columns = `id  ||  description  ||  name`
Table 'Custom_actions' Columns = `id  ||  description  ||  name ||  parameters`

Is this possible? Its better than structurally changing the database (merging the 2 tables into 1 and adding an `is_custom` column).

Comment: Why not just `select id, false As [boolItem]`?

Comment: @jpaugh I'll give it a go thanks. I'm new to such operations (setting values in a select statement)

Comment: It doesn't set a value at all. It just returns a hard-coded value of `false`. The `As [foo]` bit just sets the column name, which presumably is fixed. FWIW, I just learned about column labeling last week, from data.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just select the value `true` or `false` and use an alias to specify the the column name `IsCustom`

For example, I modified your example below to show how to do it (and also removed `AND is_custom = false/true` from the JOIN conditions because it didn't appear that there is an `is_custom` column in either table).

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.Action>> ExecuteAsync (IDbConnection conn, IDbTransaction transition, long userId)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT a.id AS Id, false AS IsCustom
                   FROM actions a
                   INNER JOIN members_actions ma ON  a.id = ma.action_id 
                   WHERE ma.member_id = :userId
                   UNION
                   SELECT a.id AS Id, true AS IsCustom 
                   FROM custom_actions a
                   INNER JOIN members_actions ma ON  a.id = ma.action_id 
                   WHERE ma.member_id = :userId;";

    return await conn.QueryAsync<Models.Action> (sql, new {userId = userId}, transition);
}
```